# does a general term exist for antecedents or postcedents?

Tags: terminology

· **endophora** is a general term that refers to either **anaphora** or **cataphora**

? does a general term exist that refers to either **antecedents** or **postcedents**

Comment: I've never seen "postcedent".  Instead, one uses "antecedent", even when the proform precedes.

Comment: _Anaphor_ is also used regardless of direction. Likewise _anaphora_. And _antecedent_ is the general term, as shown in the classic rule "An anaphor may not both precede and command its antecedent".